# Creating a Python Dictionary from another dictionary in For Loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I currently have a dictionary that I have imported from a csv file, that I have converted into a list of variables.  The original dictionary looks like this:

- server01, server01.fqdn:port
- server02, server02.fqdn:port
- server03, server03.fqdn:port
- server04, server04.fqdn:port

What I'd like to do is create another dictionary using the same key value as the existing (which would be the server name) and using the server's FQDN, use python requests to get a value.  This would create a dictionary like this that I could then insert into MySQL:

- server01 0.0 0.0 2020-07-06 19:59:42
- server02 0.0 0.0 2020-07-06 19:59:42
- server03 0.0 0.0 2020-07-06 19:59:42
- server04 0.0 0.0 2020-07-06 19:59:42

I can print the results to screen using this, but how would I insert this into a new dictionary?

```
curtime = ('{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}'.format(datetime.datetime.utcnow()))

for key, value in sorted(dict.items()):
    print key, fc_grab(value), fs_grab(value), curtime
```

Thank you,

Sean

Comment: what exactly do you want the values of the dictionary to be? The time, the ip or a tuple of both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this,

```
print key, fc_grab(value), fs_grab(value), curtime
```

You can do

```
output_dictionary[key] = "{} {} {}".format(fc_grab(value), fs_grab(value), curtime)
```

assuming that you put at the start something like

```
output_dictionary = {}
```

There are other possibilities if you don't want to just save the values as a string like what you are printing

for example you could do

```
output_dictionary[key] = (fc_grab(value), fs_grab(value), curtime)
```

then you are just putting a tuple with the three values, and you can always format them as a string later if you want, but you have the actual data items to manipulate if you want (especially if they are not just strings)

By the way, you might want to update to python3 - it is obviously from your `print` statement that you are using python2.

Comment: Thank you, that's pretty much what I was looking for because the fc_grab and fs_values need to be kept as integers so I can insert them into MySQL

Answer (score 0):

```py
curtime = ('{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}'.format(datetime.datetime.utcnow()))

results = dict()

for key, value in sorted(dict.items()):
    results[key] = {
        "fc": fc_grab(value),
        "fs": fs_grab(value),
        "curtime": curtime
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need a List of Dicts or Dict of Dicts  for inserting in MYSQL.

```
curtime = ('{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}'.format(datetime.datetime.utcnow()))
rows = {key:{  
               "fc":fc_grab(value),
               "fs":fs_grab(value),
               "curtime":curtime
           }for key, value in sorted(dict.items())}
```